# How to send message to news feed with facebook sdk php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to send message to news feed of user, i'm doing it with the code bellow but it does not go to news feed, it only go to user page.

```
<?php
require "src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'=>'xxx',
'secret'=>'xxx',
'cookie'=>true
));

$usuario = $facebook->getUser();

if(!$usuario)
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email,publish_stream'));
    echo "<script> document.location=\"".$login_url."\"; </script>";
}


$facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',array('message'=>'msg via api','link'=>'www.google.com','privacy'=>array('value'=>'CUSTOM','friends'=>'SELF')));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** choose what should go to the user's friends' news feed (nor top stories). This is decided by Facebook internal algorithms AND the user's friend.

Comment: i'm asking it cuz some users receive it in news feed others not, could u explain it?

Comment: Please check my update, as I said it's decided by Facebook **AND** the friend's settings and preferences.